# Spring MVC Controller pre process request body

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request

I am working on spring REST APIs. In requirements, there are 2 POST requests with same URL but different request body. Since Spring MVC must have unique mappings across controller, I have to pre-process the request body to map to a specific POJO.

On the basis of session_type in request body, I have to map the request to specific POJO (JSON -> JAVA POJO).

For example, if 'session_type' in request body is 'typeX' then the request should map to ClassX POJO. If 'session_type' in request body is 'typeY' then the request should map to ClassY POJO.

If there a way to do it using some kind of requestbody annotation?

Comment: Why don't your change your URIs to `/context/resources/typex` and `/context/resources/typey`?

Comment: Its a requirement that the URLs must be same since there is a difference only in SessionType.

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you explain what "session type" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Its just a field in my request body for e.g. here is my sample request body:--

{
 "session_type": "typeX",
 "first_name": "abc", etc.... 
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to bind `typeX` and `typeY`, then you definitely need 2 handlers. But, why wouldn't we use `param` option of `@RequestMapping`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        value = "/url", params = "session_type=typeX")
public String handleTypeX(@RequestBody @ModelAttribute TypeX typeX){
    //TODO implement
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/url", params = "session_type=typeY")
public String handleTypeY(@RequestBody @ModelAttribute TypeY typeY){
    //TODO implement
}
```

If you need some preparations (f.e. normalize params or perform model binding manually), then the approach above you may combine along with `@InitBinder`, but please note, that `@InitBinder` needs exact ULR's rules along with `@ModelAttribute` parameters in handlers.

**EDIT**: In Spring MVC there is no possibility to use 2 handlers for *exact URL*, i.e. when method/URL/params/consumes type are the same.

Thus I suggest use unified handler, where you would check necessary parameter and then manually convert into corresponding class. For finding necessary class I suppose it would be better to use [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```
//class resolver according "session_type" parameter
//note, that you can use Spring autowiring capabilities
private final Map<String, Class> TYPES_CONTEXT = new HashMap<String, Class>(){
    {
        this.put("x", TypeX.class);
        this.put("y", TypeY.class);
        //TODO probably other classes
    }
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/url")
public @ResponseBody String handleAnyType(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body){
    String sessionType = body.get("session_type");

    //TODO handle case if sessionType is NULL

    Class convertedClass = TYPES_CONTEXT.get(sessionType);

    //TODO handle case if class is not found

    Object actualObject = objectMapper.convertValue(body, convertedClass);

    //now we use reflection for actual handlers, but you may refactor this in the way you want, f.e. again with Strategy pattern
    //note that current approach there should be contract for methods names
    Method actualHandler = this.getClass().getMethod("handle" + actualObject.getClass().getSimpleName());

    return (String)actualHandler.invoke(this, actualObject);
}

public String handleTypeX(TypeX typeX){
    //TODO implement
}

public String handleTypeY(TypeY typeY){
    //TODO implement
}

//TODO probably other methods
```

This approach doesn't handle validation and some things were omitted, but I believe this might be helpful.

Comment: I could have used the param option if etal the type was passed as a param in URL for.eg. POST /v1/sessions?sessionType=TypeX. But, unfortunately in my case the sessionType is passed in request body. For e.g. here is my request body:

{
 "session_type": "typeX",
 "first_name": "abc",
 .... etc... 
}

Just on the "session_type" I have to decide the request-body to POJO mapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot... That seems to be the best solution for me. Appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accept answer then, if it is suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should created controller with one method for both types, and call required component\method in it depending on `typeX` or `typeY`.

Comment: That means changing the URL and having specific URL for specific Session type. Thats NOT the requirement. It says that I should create session objects for the client on the basis of SESSION_TYPE passed in REQUEST BODY. So I kind of (not exactly) need an interceptor before mapping the incoming request body to a specific POJO. Depending on session_type field in (JSON) request body I will have to map it to specific POJO.

Answer (score 0):

GETs shouldn't have request bodies, or at least if they do, [the server side isn't required to do anything with them](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/9962). As you describe it, this API isn't RESTful.

Assuming you don't care about that, try creating a controller method that takes a parent class of TypeX and TypeY, or interface that both TypeX and TypeY implement, annotate it with @SomethingMeaningfulToYou, then use a [web argument method resolver](http://sergialmar.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/extending-handler-method-argument-resolution-in-spring-mvc/) to instantiate the child class you want.

It's a hack around a broken API though.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Its actually a POST request. I edited the question.

Comment: Ah, ok. If it's coming in over JSON, make the method take a parent class parameter, and then somehow configure the Jackson ObjectMapper used by MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter to discriminate based on the sessionType. Take a look at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization for details.

Comment: And if that works, post the details as an answer so people can refer to it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> there are 2 POST requests with same URL but different request body

For a RESTful interface, the same URL should always indicate the same *resource*. The body of a request may contain different *representations* of that resource. You could create different `HttpMessageContverter` classes for the two different kinds of representation.